# PayPal Return ?PayerID=

Tags: php, pdo, paypal, paypal-sandbox

PayPal return **index.php?PayerID=N3QKU3H2STQZN** after payment is done , and my function addCash is ignored .

It worked on previous webserver(deleted) and i dont know if i have any missing extensions on php.ini

System Info
Centos 7 +PHP Version 7.4.28

Header.php

```
$paypal_email = getJsonSettings("paypal");
```

Function AddCash that is executed after payment is done.

```
function addCash($account_id, $coins)
    {
        global $database;

        $stmt = $database->runQueryAccount("UPDATE user SET credit = credit + ? WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $coins, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $account_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

Function donate.php

```
<?php
    $jsondataDonate = file_get_contents('include/db/donate.json');
    $jsondataDonate = json_decode($jsondataDonate, true);
    
    $jsondataCurrency = file_get_contents('include/db/currency.json');
    $jsondataCurrency = json_decode($jsondataCurrency,true);
    
    if(isset($_POST["method"]) && strtolower($_POST["method"])=='paypal' && isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['type']))
    {
        $return_url = $site_url."index.php";
        $cancel_url = $site_url."index.php";
        $notify_url = $site_url."paypal.php";
        
        $querystring = '';
        $querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";
        
        $price = $jsondataDonate[$_POST['id']]['list'][$_POST['type']];
        
        $querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($jsondataDonate[$_POST['id']]['name'].' ['.$price['price'].' - '.$price['cash'].' Cash]')."&";
        $querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($price['price'])."&";
        $querystring .= "noshipping=1"."&";
        $querystring .= "cmd=".urlencode(stripslashes("_xclick"))."&";
        $querystring .= "no_note=".urlencode(stripslashes("1"))."&";
        $querystring .= "currency_code=".urlencode(stripslashes($price['currency']))."&";
        $querystring .= "bn=".urlencode(stripslashes("PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest"))."&";
        $querystring .= "first_name=".urlencode(stripslashes(getAccountName($_SESSION['id'])))."&";
        
        $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
        $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
        $querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url)."&";
        $querystring .= "item_number=".urlencode($jsondataDonate[$_POST['id']]['name'].' ['.$price['price'].' - '.$price['cash'].' Cash]')."&";
        $querystring .= "custom=".urlencode($_SESSION['id']);
        
        $url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring;
        if(!headers_sent()) {
            header('Location: '.$url);
            exit;
        } else {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
            echo '</script>';
            echo '<noscript>';
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
            echo '</noscript>';
            exit;
        }
        
        exit();
    }
?>
```

paypal.php

```
 <?php
    include 'include/functions/header.php';

    if (isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && isset($_POST["txn_type"]) && isset($_POST["item_name"]) && isset($_POST["item_number"]) && isset($_POST["payment_status"]) && isset($_POST["mc_gross"])&& isset($_POST["mc_currency"])&& isset($_POST["receiver_email"])&& isset($_POST["custom"]))
    {
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }

        $data['item_name']          = $_POST['item_name'];
        $data['item_number']        = $_POST['item_number'];
        $data['payment_status']     = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $data['payment_amount']     = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $data['payment_currency']   = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $data['txn_id']             = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $data['receiver_email']     = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $data['payer_email']        = $_POST['payer_email'];
        $data['custom']             = $_POST['custom'];

        $curl_result=$curl_err='';
        $ch = curl_init();
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-Length: " . strlen($req)));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

        $curl_result = curl_exec($ch);
        $curl_err = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        
        if (strpos($curl_result, "VERIFIED")!==false && strtolower($data['receiver_email']) == strtolower($paypal_email)) {
            
            $jsondataDonate = file_get_contents('include/db/donate.json');
            $jsondataDonate = json_decode($jsondataDonate, true);
            
            foreach($jsondataDonate as $key => $donate)
                if(strtolower($donate['name'])=="paypal")
                    foreach($donate['list'] as $list)
                    {
                        $type = $donate['name'].' ['.$list['price'].' - '.$list['cash'].' Cash]';
                        if($type==$data['item_name'] && $list['price']==$data['payment_amount'] && $data['payment_currency']==$list['currency'])
                            addCash($data['custom'], $list['cash']);
                    }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: It would appear IPN verification is failing, and that this is what you need to debug.

Comment: @PrestonPHX how to do that ? cannot access paypal.php directly

Comment: `string(430) "?business=sb-q7t47o8707421%40business.example.com&item_name=PayPal+%5B2+-+9999+Cash%5D&amount=2&cmd=_xclick&no_note=1&currency_code=EUR&bn=PP-BuyNowBF%3Abtn_buynow_LG.gif%3ANonHostedGuest&first_name=admin&return=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2FWEB%2Findex.php&cancel_return=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2FWEB%2Findex.php&notify_url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2FWEB%2Fpaypal.php&item_number=PayPal+%5B2+-+9999+Cash%5D&custom=1741"`

Comment: Modify the file. Add logging. Determine what is going wrong. For example, see whether it is able to connect to the PayPal endpoint to verify the IPN. If it is not able to connect, of course it will not be able to verify the IPN.

Comment: @PrestonPHX i dont know in wich file to look, paypal.php or donate.php

Comment: In the code you posted, paypal.php is the one doing IPN verification.

Comment: @PrestonPHX handshake from paypal verification is with success, problem comes from `$notify_url = $site_url."paypal.php";`

Comment: What problem, exactly? What is it setting a wrong notify URL -- and if so, have you fixed it already?

Comment: Not yet, i thought is from there but no, nobody have an answer, what is wrong here

Comment: Okay. If verification is successful then you hare more debugging to do about what happens after that verified response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$type = $donate['name']; if($type==$data['item_name'] && $list['price']==$data['payment_amount'] && $data['payment_currency']==$list['currency']){ addCash($data['custom'], $list['cash']); }`